# I made a stack using linked list (without array), but my pop function is not working

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, singly-linked-list

In my pop function, I am storing the address of head in `temp` and then going forward. When I get a dead-end in `temp`, I remove it by assigning `NULL` to it. When I am printing the stack however, it is not removing the last push.

I have tried using `temp->next=NULL` . Only then it is working, but if `temp->next=NULL` is working. Shouldn't `temp=NULL` also work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct student
{
    char name[20];
    int id;
    double cgpa;
    struct student* next;
} *head;

void print()
{
    struct student* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("id %d name %s cgpa %lf\n", temp->id, temp->name, temp->cgpa);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void push(struct student* temp)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        return;
    }
    struct student* current = head;
    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next=temp;
}

void pop()
{
    struct student* temp = head;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n no element to pop\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char operation;
    struct student* temp = NULL;
    head = NULL;

    while(1)
    {
        // a for ADD, r for POP, s for print
        scanf("%c", &operation);
        if(operation == 'a')
        {
            temp = (struct student*)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
            scanf("%d %s %lf", &temp->id, &temp->name, &temp->cgpa);
            temp->next = NULL;
            push(temp);
        }
        else if(operation == 'r')
        {
            pop();
        }
        else if(operation == 's')
        {
            print();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
a
1 joy 2.3
a
5 boy 3.3
s
r
s
```

The expected result should be:

```
1 joy 2.3
5 boy 3.3

1 joy 2.3
```

But the actual results are

```
1 joy 2.3
5 boy 3.3

1 joy 2.3
5 boy 3.3
```

Comment: I would imagine `pop` function to return something....BTW, you *really* should fix your code formatting.

Comment: @Hasibur Rahman Shovon Please format the code to make it readable.

Comment: @Aconcagua No, it has a stack. He adds new nodes to the end and pops them from the end.:)

Comment: I allowed myself to adjust the formatting. A bit of whitespace helps improving readability, more important, though, is consequent and consistent indentation – one can see immediately where code blocks begin and end without having to search explicitly for the braces. You might have a look at different [coding styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Brace_placement_in_compound_statements), I personally recommend Allman style (which is what I formatted your code to).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oh, [@*#+$!], overlooked that...Then the other way round: A stack using a linked list is much simpler handled (and much more efficient) if pushing to and popping from front...

Comment: @Aconcagua I agree.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow *'[...] much simpler [...]'* – that part was intended for Hasibur...

Comment: You do not free the nodes you create, which results in a memory leak. Get used to right from the start: Every `malloc` should be accompanied by a corresponding `free`, so whenever you do the former, have the latter in mind at the same time!

Comment: The algorithm here is nonsense. A stack is supposed to be easy because one just always put a new plate on top and take the topmost plate when needed, but you're putting the latest plate under the stack... I.e. even *after* the fixes proposed here it is rubbish.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your right that the pop would not work.  All you are is setting the temp pointer to NULL when you found the end element.  What you need to do is to free the element at temp first, and then set the pointer that points to it from the previous element to NULL.

```
void pop()
{
    if(head==NULL){
       printf("\n no element to pop\n");
}
else
{
   struct student* temp=head;
    struct student* previous=head;
    while(temp->next!=null){
        previous=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(previous!=next) //if there was more than one
    {
      previous->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
     head=NULL;
    }

    free(temp);


}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function changes the local variable `temp` instead of changing the data member `next` of the node before the last node of the list.

It can look the following way

```
void pop()
{
    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        printf("\n no element to pop\n");
    }
    else
    {
            struct student **temp = &head;

            while ( ( *temp )->next != NULL )
            {
                temp = &( *temp )->next;
            }

            free( *temp );
            *temp = NULL;
    }
}
```

Now the variable `temp` points exactly to the data member `next` of the node before the last node. That is the list itself is changed.

Do not forget to free the last node.

Answer (score 0):

The code `temp=NULL` sets the variable `temp` to null, not the field `next` of `temp`. With the latter it isn't actually removing the node.